# XML Serialization, Include encoding info and customized namespace

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am Serializing MyXMLData class by following code

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyXMLData));
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
xmlSerializer.Serialize(fileStream, myXMLData);
fileStream.Close();
```

The output header comes something like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MyXMLData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

My questions

1) I would like to include encoding data something like`?xml version="1.0" encoding ="utf-8" ?> . How to do this?

2) I would like to change the namespace and put my own custom namesapace (This is my requirement)
instead of  `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`, I just want to have something like `xmlns="http://www.mydata.org"` .

I can read the xml file and replace the contents once it is written, but I would like to know, is there anyway to do this in one step when the xml file is written?

Comment: Which language are you using? Java or c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works fine as expected

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyXMLData));

XmlSerializerNamespaces ns1 = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns1.Add("", "http://www.mydata.org");

Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, false, encoding))
{
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(sw, myXMLData, ns1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following steps.
1. To achieve your first requirement:

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyXMLData));
var fname = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "filename.xml");
var appendMode = false;
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fname, appendMode, encoding))
{
      xmlSerializer.Serialize(sw, MyXMLData);
}
```

2. To achieve the second requirement

To the constructor of the XMLSerializer class, add the namespace like this: 
    `XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyXMLData), "http://www.mydata.org");`